# PHP: Basic Auth Encryption

Tags: php, base64, basic-authentication

I am generating a Basic Auth and I don't know how the algorithm works.
I know it is encoded in base64.

as for example `admin:admin` = `Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=`

How can I generate `Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=` using `admin:admin` pattern? I will need the keys to be stored in the database that's why I need to know the algorithm of the encoding

Comment: `"Basic " . base64_encode("admin:admin")`?

Comment: `It's encoded in base64`.... so hadn't you considered [base64_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)?

Comment: Did the answer resolve your issue? If so, mark it, if it was useful upvote. If it was neither have the curtsy to comment on it instead of leaving it 'hanging'

Answer (score 1):

Don't use encoding or a hashing algorithm for authentication, use encryption instead.

Anyways:

```
echo base64_encode('admin:admin')      // YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
echo base64_decode('YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=') // admin:admin
```